# querying information from next row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created this SQL and dont know how to query the next row. We use SQL 2008 so cant use lag/lead

```sql
SELECT P_MTN AS MTN
  ,P_DATE AS DATE
  ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), SEQU) AS NUM
  ,item_id + '  ||  ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), PRODUCTION_ID) + '  ||  ' + 
    display_description AS ITEM_1
FROM dbo.Equipment INNER JOIN
  dbo.ERAT ON SEQUENCE = SEQU INNER JOIN
  Track.dbo.item_link ON link_id = PRODUCTION_ID INNER JOIN
  Track.dbo.LinkParentDescription ON item_id = item_id
ORDER BY NUM ASC
```

Basically what I want to do is..

If the NUM value is the same as the next row's NUM value then add a new column populated with

```
item_id + '  ||  ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), PRODUCTION_ID) + '  ||  ' + display_description AS ITEM_2
```

using the info from the next row.

I've had to anonnymise this code as I was told to do so, so hopefully the code is still valid (lol)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a window function on SQL Server 2008?  The equivalent of LEAD:

```sql
MAX(NUM) OVER(ORDER BY NUM ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING)
```

This expression will give you the `NUM` value of the next row, where the rows are ordered by `NUM` ascending.  Then just do a comparison with a `CASE` expression:

```sql
CASE 
  WHEN NUM = MAX(NUM) OVER(ORDER BY NUM ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) 
    THEN item_id + '  ||  ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), PRODUCTION_ID) + '  ||  ' 
         + display_description
  ELSE YYY
END AS ITEM_2
```

Comment: i get a Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS' when using that script

Comment: Hmm...it looks like that's not supported in 2008 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686140/issue-with-window-function-in-mssql-2008-r2.  Sorry about that.